# How to find the total number of rows between dates in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have to find the drinker and the total number of drinks ordered by each drinker in the first three months of 2020.

Here is my SELECT statement so far: (It doesn't present any errors, but doesn't return anything either)

```
SELECT DRINKER, COUNT(DRINK)
FROM ORDERS 
WHERE ODATE >= STR_TO_DATE('01-JAN-2020','%D-%M-%Y') 
AND ODATE <= STR_TO_DATE('31-MAR-2020','%D-%M-%Y')
GROUP BY DRINKER;
```

Here is the CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS(    /* Drinkers visit pubs and consumes drinks */
DRINKER     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drinker name */
PUB         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Pub name */
ODATE       DATE        NOT NULL,   /* Order date   */
DRINK       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drink name   */
DRINK_NO    DECIMAL(2)  NOT NULL,   /* A sequence number of a drink */
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(DRINKER, PUB, ODATE, DRINK, DRINK_NO),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(PUB, DRINK) REFERENCES SERVES(PUB, DRINK),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(DRINKER) REFERENCES DRINKERS(DRINKER)   );
```

Here is an example of the data that has been inserted into the table ORDERS:

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 3);
```

It should also be worth noting that I am working in MYSQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `%D` should be `%d`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, but there is still not return

Comment: It works here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9pAFfhmvHsUb8QMTyRZ5FQ/0

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks. But if you take a proper look, you'll notice I have displayed those changes.

Comment: @RiggsFolly He did that in response to my comment, before the answer was posted. I didn't think it was worth an answer.

Comment: But strictly, that also makes your comment look foolish when in fact it was the answer :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was planning to close it as a typo, until he posted that it didn't solve the problem for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a lower-case `d` for the day of the month.  So this works:

```
SELECT DRINKER, COUNT(DRINK)
FROM ORDERS 
WHERE ODATE >= STR_TO_DATE('01-JAN-2020','%d-%M-%Y') AND
      ODATE <= STR_TO_DATE('31-MAR-2020','%d-%M-%Y')
GROUP BY DRINKER;
```

However, this is more sensibly written as:

```
SELECT DRINKER, COUNT(DRINK)
FROM ORDERS 
WHERE ODATE >= '2020-01-01'AND
      ODATE <= '2020-03-31'
GROUP BY DRINKER;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f21a22374f782bdf419bf884e459d7f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @Barmar thank you. Do you have any idea why it is working in the fiddle, but not in MYSQL? I have made sure that the rows have been inserted correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're doing differently from us.